# PDF report maven configuration with sonar-maven3-plugin 3.5.1 verstion

Tags: pdf-generation, maven-3, sonarqube

I am using sonar-maven3-plugin 3.5.1 and i don't know how to configure PDF report for this plugin. Is sonar-maven3-plugin uses any internal plugin for report. I don't know how and where to configure the reporting plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Sonar 4.0+ the plugin is included with the base install. The PDF is generated automatically when you run `mvn sonar:sonar`, but the dashboard doesn't contain the PDF widget by default. Add it by going to Dashboards > Configure Widgets. Search for and add the PDF widget.

Answer (score 1):

I guess starting by reading the documentation page might be a good starting point : http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PDF+Plugin

Comment: I have gone through the above link, couldn't able to figure the repository from to load the the Sonar-maven3-plunin 3.5.1.

Comment: Could you attach your error log file because I don't manage to figure out why you're talking about the Sonar-maven3-plugin if your "only" issue relates to the PDF report plugin ?