# Don't find PDF report in sonar qube GUI

Tags: pdf-generation, maven-3, sonarqube

I have used sonar-maven3-plugin 3.5.1 version to generate PDF report. I have followed the steps as follows:

**Dependency in pom:**

```
dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.pdf-report</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-pdfreport-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**Goal:**

```
      mvn Sonar:sonar
```

I could able to see the PDF report generated under **target/sonar/** folder. But when i open Sonar Qube GUI from **//localhost:9000**, I don't find any PDF file generated for my Project. Where should i look for that PDF file in Sonar Qube GUI

Comment: This question duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324184/pdf-report-maven-configuration-with-sonar-maven3-plugin-3-5-1-verstion

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Google Chrome to get Sonar report in PDF format. Please find below the steps:

1. Use Google Chrome to open the sonar report as custom dashboard
2. Just press 'ctrl+P'
3. Change the printer settings 'pdf'
4. And save the file

By this way you can the report in PDF format.